# how to convert JSON data into dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I got a JSON data like this:

```
jsonData = {
  "0":{
    "columnA":"a",
    "columnB":"b"
  },
  "1":{
    "columnA":"c",
    "columnB":"d"
  }
}
```

how do I convert it into a data frame like this:

```
      rowData
0    {"columnA":"a","columnB":"b"}
1    {"columnA":"c","columnB":"d"}
```

Here's what I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rowData': jsonData})
```

but I got an error:

> If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

So I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rowData': jsonData}, index=[0])
```

but it turned out:

```
      rowData
0     {"0":{"columnA":"a","columnB":"b"},"1":{"columnA":"c","columnB":"d"}}
```

Comment: for me working `df = pd.DataFrame({'rowData': jsonData})` nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working your solution nice:

```
jsonData = {
  "0":{
    "columnA":"a",
    "columnB":"b"
  },
  "1":{
    "columnA":"c",
    "columnB":"d"
  }
}

df = pd.DataFrame({'rowData': jsonData})
print (df)
                            rowData
0  {'columnA': 'a', 'columnB': 'b'}
1  {'columnA': 'c', 'columnB': 'd'}
```

If necessary convert json to dict:

```
import json

jsonData = json.dumps({
  "0":{
    "columnA":"a",
    "columnB":"b"
  },
  "1":{
    "columnA":"c",
    "columnB":"d"
  }
})

df = pd.DataFrame({'rowData': json.loads(jsonData)})
print (df)
                            rowData
0  {'columnA': 'a', 'columnB': 'b'}
1  {'columnA': 'c', 'columnB': 'd'}
```

If need json for each value in DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rowData': {k: json.dumps(v) for k, v in json.loads(jsonData).items()}})
print (df)
                            rowData
0  {"columnA": "a", "columnB": "b"}
1  {"columnA": "c", "columnB": "d"}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's similar to what I want. But I need it to be JSON type in rowData. Is this possible?

Comment: @Emily - Answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added your data to a list and created a dataframe from it:

```
all_data = []
for value in jsonData.values():
    all_data.append(value)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

Output:
Index columnA   columnB
0          a    b
1          c    d
```